# Embeddable reporting lost connection to cloudant

Tags: ibm-cloud, embeddable-reporting

I have a embeddable reporting service in my Bluemix app, running off a Cloudant service. It has been fine for months and then suddenly 2 days back, started throwing the attached error. Meaning that Embeddable reporting has lost the URL to Cloudant that was configured to start with. Any thoughts on what might be going on?

Cheers,
VP

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x1MFw.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

The Bluemix platform and the Cloudant service experience some availability issues late last week. All services are restored now. If you continue to experience issues, please raise an issue at [IBM developerWorks Answers](https://developer.ibm.com/answers/smart-spaces/12/bluemix.html), or open a support ticket.

Use this link to view [status for the Bluemix platform and services](https://developer.ibm.com/bluemix/support/#status).

Comment: So, I raised a support ticket and heres the response: 

Hello VP,

 Please note that the ERS service is about to be sunset on the 15th of May and will not be available after this date. 

As you might already be aware, BETA services can be withdrawn any time which is what the ERS team is doing. There is no alternative for ERS service. So if you would like I will pursue this issue with the ERS team as to why adding Cloudant Service is throwing the error. But as this service will be going out of service, I suggest you would need to look into other options.

I apologize for the inconvenience.

Comment: Just annoyed that the POC that I built went up in smoke. Not to mention the embarrassment before a potential customer :(